# How to filter both checkbox and dropdown using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am working on php based webapp which consist of both checkbox and dropdown if i am filtering only checkbox it is working fine but when integrate dropdown on same the result shows nothing .
Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        var action  =  'fetch_data';
        var jobtype =  get_filter('jobtype');//checkbox
        var salary  =  get_filter('salary');//checkbox
        $('#category').change(function(){  //dropdown
           var category = $(this).val(); 

        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action,jobtype:jobtype,salary:salary,category:category},
            success:function(data){

                $('.filter_data').html(data);

            }
        });
    }}

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
             $('#pleasehide').hide();
            filter.push($(this).val());

        });
        return filter;
    }
    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

});
</script>
```

fetch_data.php

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1'
 ";

 if(isset($_POST["jobtype"]))
 {
    $jobtype_filter = implode("','", $_POST["jobtype"]);
    $query .= "
    AND  JType IN('".$jobtype_filter."')";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["salary"]))
 {
    $salary_filter = implode("','", $_POST["salary"]);
    $query .= "
    AND  SalFro IN('".$salary_filter."')";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["category"]))
 {
    $category =  $_POST["category"]);
    $query .= "
    AND  category like('".$category."')";
 }
remaining sql code
```

when i add category code in fetch_data section the result shows nothing

Comment: What is the resulting `$query`? Do you have database entries with a category? You can test queries directly at the database without  php

Comment: Previously when I have not included category code it is filtering fine but after that the result does not ahow

Comment: Remove the closing round bracket at `$_POST["category"])`.

Answer (score 0):

Peace be upon you and God's mercy

The solution my friend
is to repeat the process

---

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

  filter_data();

  function filter_data() {

    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var id = <?php echo $IdCat ?>;
    var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
    var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();

    var tag_1 = get_filter('tag_1');
    var tag_2 = get_filter('tag_2');
    var tag_3 = get_filter('tag_3');
    var status = get_filter('status');
    var tag_4 = get_filter('tag_4');
    var tag_5 = get_filter('tag_5');
    //console.log(tag_2);   console.log(tag_3);
    $.ajax({
      url: "includes/templates/fetch_data.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        action: action,
        id: id,
        minimum_price: minimum_price,
        maximum_price: maximum_price,
        tag_1: tag_1,
        tag_2: tag_2,
        tag_3: tag_3,
        tag_4: tag_4,
        tag_5: tag_5,
        status: status
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log('ok');
        $('#filter_data').html(data);
      }
    });

    $('#select').on('change', function selects() {
      var selects = $(this).val();
      console.log(selects);
      $.ajax({
        url: "includes/templates/fetch_data.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          action: action,
          id: id,
          minimum_price: minimum_price,
          maximum_price: maximum_price,
          tag_1: tag_1,
          tag_2: tag_2,
          tag_3: tag_3,
          tag_4: tag_4,
          tag_5: tag_5,
          status: status,
          order: selects
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log('ok');
          $('#filter_data').html(data);
        }
      });

    });

  }


  function get_filter(class_name) {
    var filter = [];
    $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function() {
      filter.push($(this).val());
    });
    return filter;
  }
  $('.common_selector').click(function() {
    filter_data();
  });
  $('#price_range').slider({
    range: true,
    min: <?php echo $price['Price'] ?>,
    max: <?php echo $pricemax['Price'] ?>,

    orientation: "horizontal",
    values: [<?php echo $price['Price'] ?>, <?php echo $pricemax['Price'] ?>],
    step: 10,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
      $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
      $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
      filter_data();
    }
  });



});
```